# Function cant be read Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, web

why does baseApi cant be read on the renderImage i tried everything but it isn't working I tried props and state but not working also

```
componentDidMount() {
        let baseApi = this.props.lenk('files/');
        this.baseApi(baseApi);
    }

 baseApi(link){
            return link;
        }

    renderImage(i,d) {
            debugger

            var Link= i.Link;
            var file = i.Name;
            let baseApi =this.baseApi();
}
```

any idea i can get the value of the baseApi thank you in advance

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: First you call the `baseApi` method, but do nothing with the returned value. Then you call it again with no argument, so it returns `undefined`.

Comment: when i debugged it  says the this.baseApi is undefined

Comment: @pawel im confuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one

```
constructor() {
 super();
 this.renderImage= this.renderImage.bind(this);
 //this.baseApi= this.baseApi.bind(this);
}
```

Where you used renderImage , if in render may be cycle function not correct for this logic.Should try

```
componentWillMount() //instead of componentDidMount
```